# Trying to load the csv file from github user, however its throwing error. stating that url error

Tags: python

Anyone can help me fix this below error?

```py
df=pd.read_csv('https://github.com/krameshdn/krameshdn/blob/1ad67512c81f30722831ae3e2290fc853040474a/Concrete_Data.csv')
```

error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Comment: Try `pd.read_html`

Comment: Please provide an example of the contents of the `csv` file please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the data is not `csv` but it is `html` with `csv` data contained within it. This is why it fails.  for example, the same code with this site (csv file) works:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with request module along with csv module

```
import csv
import urllib.request

url = "https://github.com/krameshdn/krameshdn/blob/1ad67512c81f30722831ae3e2290fc853040474a/Concrete_Data.csv"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = csv.reader(lines)

for row in data:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, however still I am getting same error

Comment: `lines` is not defined, so this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that the url is not a `csv`, but a `html` file. In order to get the `raw csv`, you have to modify the url to this:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/krameshdn/krameshdn/1ad67512c81f30722831ae3e2290fc853040474a/Concrete_Data.csv
```

So here is the full code (with the ammended url explicitly shown):

```py
import pandas as pd

# this does not work
url = 'https://github.com/krameshdn/krameshdn/blob/1ad67512c81f30722831ae3e2290fc853040474a/Concrete_Data.csv'
# convert url to raw and this works
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/krameshdn/krameshdn/1ad67512c81f30722831ae3e2290fc853040474a/Concrete_Data.csv' 

df=pd.read_csv(url)
```

Here is the result:

```
      Cement  Blast  Fly Ash  Water  Superplasticizer      CA     FA  Age    CMS
0      540.0    0.0      0.0  162.0               2.5  1040.0  676.0   28  79.99
1      540.0    0.0      0.0  162.0               2.5  1055.0  676.0   28  61.89
2      332.5  142.5      0.0  228.0               0.0   932.0  594.0  270  40.27
3      332.5  142.5      0.0  228.0               0.0   932.0  594.0  365  41.05
4      198.6  132.4      0.0  192.0               0.0   978.4  825.5  360  44.30
...      ...    ...      ...    ...               ...     ...    ...  ...    ...
1025   276.4  116.0     90.3  179.6               8.9   870.1  768.3   28  44.28
1026   322.2    0.0    115.6  196.0              10.4   817.9  813.4   28  31.18
1027   148.5  139.4    108.6  192.7               6.1   892.4  780.0   28  23.70
1028   159.1  186.7      0.0  175.6              11.3   989.6  788.9   28  32.77
1029   260.9  100.5     78.3  200.6               8.6   864.5  761.5   28  32.40

[1030 rows x 9 columns]
```